# I am trying to work with an array in php and am confused

Tags: php, arrays, csv

My csv file looks like this.

```
#file contents
EC023,2
EC026A,3
EC025,7
EC027,67
EC031,567
EC033,78
EC034,234
EC038,67
EC038A,67
EC039,60
EC039A,100
```

using the php library parsecsv I have loaded the file into an array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [EC023] => EC026A [2] => 3 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [EC023] => EC025 [2] => 7 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [EC023] => EC027 [2] => 67 )  
        [3] => Array ( [EC023] => EC031 [2] => 567 )  
        [4] => Array ( [EC023] => EC033 [2] => 78 )  
        [5] => Array ( [EC023] => EC034 [2] => 234 )  
        [6] => Array ( [EC023] => EC038 [2] => 67 )  
        [7] => Array ( [EC023] => EC038A [2] => 67 )  
        [8] => Array ( [EC023] => EC039 [2] => 60 )  
        [9] => Array ( [EC023] => EC039A [2] => 100 ) )
```

but I need to work with each set of data.  For instance in the first row I need to create a variable $code='EC023' and $qty=2

I have been working with Mysql data in PHP for years but this is the first time I have tried to import a csv file and process it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: there went something wrong with parsecsv. It took the first line as 'header', which you now have as array keys. There might be an option to turn that off?

Comment: now you would find the values there `$code = $array[n]['EC023']` and `$qty = $array[n][2]` - where 'n' is the indexes 0-9

Comment: Thanks, I now know what to do next.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I don't know if [this is the right library](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php), but if yes, you could do this `$csv->fields = ['cody', 'qty']`

Comment: Maybe https://3v4l.org/CIi17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you need that library to parse CSV files. Does this simpler approach work for you?

**EDIT:** Added file support. This approach easily deals with text files of 1GB or more, hundreds of millions of records like the ones you described (as long as your PHP config allows it).

```
$f = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== false) {
     // process the line read.
     $row = str_getcsv($arr[$i]); 
     $code = $row[0];
     $qty = $row[1];
     echo $code . ": " . $qty . "<br>";
}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: I don't think so.  The files will have hundreds of records scanned using a barcode scanner which then creates a csv file.  I can't see how this would work.

Comment: It does work. All you need is to open the file and read line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the file function. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php. It reads the contents of a file to an array. Each line in the file is an array element. After reading the contents of the csv file, you can use a loop to traverse the array.

Alternatively you can also use the built in php functions: [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) and [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)